# Partial derivatives of definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I'm probably overlooking something very simple, but I don't see what it is.
I want to determine the partial derivatives of the integral below, and I know the answers should be:

> $\frac{d}{dx}(\int_0^x f(yt) \,dt)=f(yx)$
>   $\frac{d}{dy}(\int_0^x f(yt) \,dt)=f(yx)x$

But when I tried to write out why this was the case again, I got a different answer for the partial derivative with respect to x:

> $\frac{d}{dx}(\int_0^x f(yt) \,dt)=\frac{d}{dx}(F(yx)-F(0))=f(yx)y$
>   $\frac{d}{dy}(\int_0^x f(yt) \,dt)=\frac{d}{dy}(F(yx)-F(0))=f(yx)x$
>   (Here $F$ denotes the antiderivative of $f$).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \int_0^x f(yt) \, \mathrm dt = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \frac{1}{y}F(yx) = f(yx) 
$$

Comment: Where does the 1/y term come from?

Comment: Try doing it the opposite way: $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} F(yx) = yf(yx)$, so naturally for the reverse we need to include a factor of $\frac{1}{y}$.

Comment: ah I see, that makes sense. Thank you!